# How to scroll a view in a ECL (RCPTT) script ?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-rcptt

In one of my tests, written in ECL with RCPTT, I need to check the value of a register. To do so I check the value shown in the registers view

[image]

The problem is that the register I'm looking for is far in the list. And the debugger load the value dynamically, when scrolling the list.

```
57-data-list-register-values --thread 1 --frame 0 x 15
57^done,register-values=[{number="15",value="0x0"}]
(gdb) 
58-data-list-register-values --thread 1 --frame 0 N 15
58^done,register-values=[{number="15",value="0"}]
```

So in order to check the value of my register, I need to force a scrolling to force the debugger to load the value. So here's my question : **how can I make the test scroll the view ?**

---

If I don't do this, the execution fail when I try to select the register using this:

```
get-view Registers | get-tree | get-item "General Registers/MY_REGISTER"
```

It throws me:

```
Failed to set selection: [[General Registers, MY_REGISTER]].
```

I've tried to use `expand-all` to force the discovery but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

If there's keyboard control in that grid, you can first focus on one of the rows (like, `click` on the top row with some fixed coordinates, or maybe just `click viewname` is enough), and then `key-type PageDown` or `key-type Down` several times.